# How to open Android pop-up view from adb?

Tags: android, adb, samsung-galaxy

in samsung galaxy s8 how open app in popup view from adb ?

[image: pop-up view]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't think "pop-up view" is a feature of Android. If your phone has such a feature it might be added as proprietary by the phone manufacturer. Unfortunately you don't tell use what device and Android version you use or other details so it is unlikely someone is able to answer your question.

Comment: samsung galaxy s8